# Why does hyperlink open from Excel create multiple IE windows?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-word-2013

I have a excel document with SageCRM link (e.g. `server/eware.dll/SessionFind?Act=ID&Mode=1&CLk=T&key0=7&key7=ID&Oppo_OpportunityId=ID`)

When clicked on this link from excel or word it opens in two IE windows but when I create new link to e.g. `google.com` it only opens in a single IE window.

So I trough it might be something to do with this  (`eware.dll/SessionFind?Act=ID&Mode=1&CLk=T&key0=7&key7=ID&Oppo_OpportunityId=ID`) so I created new link with just `link://server/` but again it open into two IE windows.

When I asked my colleague to do same thing, everything is open in single IE window.

I don't understand why my Excel and Word opening this hyperlink to server in multiple IE windows. How can I resolve this?

- Server: Windows 2008 R2
- PC: Windows 7 Enterprise 64X
- Browser: IE 11
- Office 365 (2013)

Comment: This may sound like a silly question, but are you single clicking or double clicking the hyperlink in Excel? I've seen people double click and end up with two windows.

Comment: Single click. It only happen on one PC. I have remove office reinstall, create new profile. but still same

Comment: It could be something to do with Windows. Try running `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt to check system files for integrity issues.

Comment: @CharlieRB  thank you your solution did work.

Comment: Great. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something to do with Windows. Try running [`sfc /scannow`](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833/en-us) from an elevated command prompt to check system files for integrity issues.

> System File Checker is a utility in Windows that allows users to scan
>   for corruptions in Windows system files and restore corrupted files.
>   This article describes how to run the System File Checker tool
>   (SFC.exe) to scan your system files and to repair missing or corrupted
>   system files in Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows 7 or Windows Vista. If
>   a Windows Resource Protection (WRP) file is missing or is corrupted,
>   Windows may not behave as expected. For example, some Windows
>   functions may not work, or Windows may crash.

[source](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833/en-us)

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by making a different web browser the default then resetting the default back to your preferred browser.

Comment: This didn't work for me; my default was Edge, and switching to Firefox resulted in two tabs. Then back to Edge, and still two tabs.